# Чтобы меню всегда было одинакового расстояния слева по отношению к левому блоку - кнопке

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Я бы хотел чтобы менюшки всегда были одинакового расстояния слева по отношению к слову -- Магазин (на всех экранах минимум 981px). Чего я хочу добиться - это чтобы слово -- Магазин -- было как будто частью меню, то есть менюшкой по виду. Я в хроме чего только не тыкал. На точки после слова -- Магазин -- не смотрите, я их на десктопе уберу. Сайт вот - https://brightbottle.ru/. Это Вордпресс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.container {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

#et-top-navigation {
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает. Только теперь лого по середине нужно чтобы было, оно съехало, но вы уже мне очень помогли.

Comment: Если просто маргин сделать то он не на всех экранах норм

Comment: Тут ещё продолжается тема -- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220128/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85