# Посередине лого выставить на всех экранах

Tags: html, css

Не могу посередине лого выставить на всех экранах. `margin-left: 50%;` не работает. Там есть `.logo_container`, может его сделать как то посередине и прописать тогда к нему `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` Мой сайт - https://brightbottle.ru/

Comment: посередине лого где? каких именно экранов?

Comment: ```.container``` не по середине, ```logo_container``` почему-то на всю ширину и вся разметка ....

Comment: Проблемный код или разметку сюда на сайт нужно добавлять, а не ссылку на свою страницу

Comment: #Zhihar, По середине горизонтально в хедере, где оно сейчас

Comment: #HamSter .container не посередине потому что так было нужно чтобы к слову -- Магазин -- менюшки стояли близко, -- Магазин -- не часть меню, это кнопка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.container` - убрать `max-width`

```
.logo_container {text-align: center;}
```

`#logo` - убрать всё.

Comment: Русский сайт, и все на английском, тьфу. Да еще и с ошибками.